# Fill cells with formula, adjusting one field and keeping the other

Tags: excel

I have following formula in cell `K40`:

`=CONCATENATE("['",B39,"' => '",B40,"', '",C39,"' => ",C40,", '",D39,"' => '",D40,"', '",E39,"' => '",E40,"', '",F39,"' => '",F40,"', '",G39,"' => '",G40,"', '",H39,"' => '",H40,"', '",I39,"' => '",I40,"', '",J39,"' => '",J40,"'],")`

and this formula in cell `K41`:

`=CONCATENATE("['",B39,"' => '",B41,"', '",C39,"' => ",C41,", '",D39,"' => '",D41,"', '",E39,"' => '",E41,"', '",F39,"' => '",F41,"', '",G39,"' => '",G41,"', '",H39,"' => '",H41,"', '",I39,"' => '",I41,"', '",J39,"' => '",J41,"'],")`

As you can see, for every row every odd field needs to stay the way it is, and every even field needs to increase.

I've tried to fill in this formula for the rest of rows in my table, given these two cells, but for cell `K42` Excel populated it as:

`=CONCATENATE("['",B41,"' => '",B42,"', '",C41,"' => ",C42,", '",D41,"' => '",D42,"', '",E41,"' => '",E42,"', '",F41,"' => '",F42,"', '",G41,"' => '",G42,"', '",H41,"' => '",H42,"', '",I41,"' => '",I42,"', '",J41,"' => '",J42,"'],")`

but it should be populated as:

`=CONCATENATE("['",B39,"' => '",B42,"', '",C39,"' => ",C42,", '",D39,"' => '",D42,"', '",E39,"' => '",E42,"', '",F39,"' => '",F42,"', '",G39,"' => '",G42,"', '",H39,"' => '",H42,"', '",I39,"' => '",I42,"', '",J39,"' => '",J42,"'],")`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try entering formula using `$`, it will fix the row, so it won't be adjusted when coopying formula:

`=CONCATENATE("['",B$39,"' => '",B40,"', '",C$39,"' => ",C40,", '",D$39,"' => '",D40,"', '",E$39,"' => '",E40,"', '",F$39,"' => '",F40,"', '",G$39,"' => '",G40,"', '",H$39,"' => '",H40,"', '",I$39,"' => '",I40,"', '",J$39,"' => '",J40,"'],")`